# Too many chain reorgs in a proof of authority (clique) based private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, poa, clique

I'm studying on Proof of Authority (Clique) based blockchains. I've setup private networks with 1 validator nodes few times, things really go well in 1 validator but when I add 2 / 3 validators in the network via **clique.propose**, lots of reorgs starts to happen. Sometime, reorg happens even 2-3 times every minute. Currently, I have a 3 validator based network with a block time of 5 seconds (tried longer block time such as 10sec and reorg still happens) and my geth version is 1.10.8.

It would be a great help for me if anyone can point me what can be the reason behind this reorgs and how to prevent it.

Comment: What base are you using ? Hyperledger Besu ? Having reorgs is normal and required for Clique as forks will eventually happen.

Comment: I'm using the official go-ethereum client. I see in other chains with similar configuration, reorgs happen very often. Like few times in a day, but in my case it's happening 2-3 times every minute. That shouldn't be a normal behaviour considering it's a private network with 3 validator nodes. :(